# Detecting if panel is focused in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, panel, key-bindings

I need to assign a keybinding in VSCode (alt+right/left) to switch between tabs in the panel (Terminal, Problem, output, Debug Console, etc.)

For some reason

```
"when": "panelFocus"
```

is just working for the **Terminal** and **Problem** tabs. It's not working for **Output**, **Debug Console**, and the tabs related to installed extensions (Like GitLense).

Appreciate any help

Comment: I just wrote a keybinding `{ "key": "ctrl+b", "command": "workbench.explorer.fileView.focus", "when": "panelFocus", }` and it worked in debug panel, output panel, and problems panel. What _exactly_  are you trying to do? We need more details to reproduce the problem.

Comment: `{ "key": "alt+left", "command": "workbench.action.previousPanelView", "when": "panelFocus", },` works fine for me. Does that work for you?

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. What do you see when you [troubleshoot your keybindings](//github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues)? Please paste the relevant parts of what you see into a code block in your question post.